# No se muestran los objetos en Carousel ni en ListView de MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

Estoy tratando de hacer que se vean los objetos dentro de un ObservableList en un Carousel y un ListView. Estoy siguiendo la misma dinámica en todas partes pero en esta ventana concretamente no me está funcionando y no se por qué. Pongo aquí el código:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="_3.Presentation._2.View.UsuarioPageView"
             Title="UsuarioPageView">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Spacing="15">

        <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="15">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Source="{Binding FotoPerfil}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding NombreUsuario}" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" FontSize="22" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Logros}" x:Name="CvLogros" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="red" HeightRequest="100">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <VerticalStackLayout>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Icono}"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Titulo}"/>
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>

            <ListView x:Name="LvTerrarios" ItemsSource="{Binding Terrarios}" SelectionMode="Single" HasUnevenRows="True" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Background="Cyan" HeightRequest="100">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid Padding="8" ColumnSpacing="20">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Foto}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" WidthRequest="100" Margin="0,5"/>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Descripcion}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding FechaCreacion, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
        
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
using _2.BusinessLogic;
using _3.Presentation._3.ViewModel;
using _4.Entities;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace _3.Presentation._2.View;

public partial class UsuarioPageView : ContentPage
{
    public UsuarioPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public UsuarioPageView(Usuario contacto): this()
    {
        this.BindingContext = contacto;
        ObtenerInfo(contacto);
    }

    private async void ObtenerInfo(Usuario contacto)
    {
        UsuarioViewModel viewModel = new UsuarioViewModel();

        ObservableCollection<Terrario> terrarios = await ObtenerTerrarios(contacto.Id);
        viewModel.Terrarios = terrarios;
        LvTerrarios.BindingContext = viewModel.Terrarios;

        ObservableCollection<Logro> logros = await ObtenerLogros(contacto.Id);
        viewModel.Logros = logros;
        CvLogros.BindingContext = viewModel.Logros;
    }

    private async Task<ObservableCollection<Terrario>> ObtenerTerrarios(long userId)
    {
        List<Terrario> terrarios = await Herramientas.GetTerrariosUsuario(userId);
        return new ObservableCollection<Terrario>(terrarios);
    }

    private async Task<ObservableCollection<Logro>> ObtenerLogros(long userId)
    {
        List<Logro> logros= await Herramientas.GetLogrosUsuario(userId);
        return new ObservableCollection<Logro>(logros);
    }
}
```

```
using _4.Entities;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace _3.Presentation._3.ViewModel
{
    public class UsuarioViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Terrario> _terrarios;
        public ObservableCollection<Terrario> Terrarios
        {
            get { return _terrarios; }
            set
            {
                if(_terrarios != value )
                {
                    _terrarios = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Logro> _logros;
        public ObservableCollection<Logro> Logros
        {
            get { return _logros; }
            set
            {
                if (_logros != value)
                {
                    _logros = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

En el viewmodel estoy poniendo dos ObservableLists, de Logros y de Terrarios, como en el resto de viewmodels salvo que este es el único que tiene dos listados distintos, aunque ya he probado a quitarle el de logros y sigue sin funcionar.

Por lo demás, el ContextBinding de cada elemento creo que lo pongo correctamente, no he conseguido sacar el error en ningún sitio. ¿Alguna idea?